# HTML / CSS Layout in Photoshop

Tags: html, css, user-interface, user-experience

I want to build a user interface in `Photoshop` and port to my `Visual Studio`. what is the correct height and width for the canvas to be used and ported in order to export the `HTML / CSS`

Comment: If you look at the tutorials found by searching for "how to design a website in photoshop" you will find various criteria to select sizes.

Comment: Ideally you'd be using multiple size canvas' to make your website responsive. There are plenty of tutorials online that will give you this, plus a lot more information regarding your question. On another note, I'd recommend using Adobe XD instead of PhotoShop. (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-standard-canvas-size-of-Photoshop-for-Web-Design)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [Adobe XD](https://www.adobe.com/de/products/xd.html). You can use there templates for website so you also have good sizes. But always remember, that you often have to readjust sizes, either way.